# Gson Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, json, gson

All StackOverflow answers didn't help me out. My JSON looks correct according to them and all other places that I search, it seems fine.

I can't load my JSON file in Java and I really need help at this.

Here's my JSON

```
{"evento":
 {"descricao":"saf","finalizado":false,"id":1,"localEvento":"asufgb","nome":"Teste",
  "convidados":
   [{"acompanhante":null,"id":"28147",
     "localHospedagem":"ATLANTE PLAZA","nome":"FooBar","nomeCracha":"FOO","observacoes":null,"participante":null,
     "publico":"FROTISTAS"}
   ]}}
```

Here's my code

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)));

JsonObject obj = parser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();

Evento evento = gson.fromJson(obj.get("evento"), Evento.class);
```

And the Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.expect(JsonTreeReader.java:139)
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line of your code is triggering the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'd likely take the following approach.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class App
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Evento evento = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), EventoWrapper.class).evento;
    System.out.println(evento.descricao);
  }
}

class EventoWrapper
{
    Evento evento;
}

class Evento
{
    String descricao;
    String finalizado;
    int id;
    String localEvento;
    String nome;
    List<Convidado> convidados;
}

class Convidado
{
    String acompanhante;
    int id;
    String localHospedagem;
    String nome;
    String nomeCracha;
    String observacoes;
    String participante;
    String publico;
}
```